# Generating list of dates from range of 2 years

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create list of sorted dates. I can't use external libs such as moment.js. It needs to be formatted in year-month way with range of 2 years divided by months. I did list of months and it works for me but I have problem with years (in attached example it is doesn't work well).
Do you have any idea or suggestions how to improve this list?

```js
var today = new Date();

var months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];

var initalList = [];

var previousYear = today.getFullYear() -1;
var aMonth = today.getMonth();

for (var i=0; i<25; i++) {
    initalList.push({month: months[aMonth], year: previousYear, myDate: previousYear + '-' + months[aMonth]});
    if(i > 12) {
        previousYear = today.getFullYear();
    }
    aMonth++;
    if(aMonth > 11) {
        aMonth = 0;
    }
}
initalList.shift();

console.log(initalList)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I generated list of past 24 months but I can't connect it to proper years.

Comment: Change your if condition from `if(i > 12) {` to `if(i >= 12) {`

Comment: Yes but if the month will change in next year it won't work I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to substract the month, the native Date will do that you need. See the example bellow:

```js
var dates = [];
var now = new Date();
var numberOfPastMonths = 24;

var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth();
//months quantity
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfPastMonths; i++){
   //you only need to substract the months
   dates.push(new Date(year, month - i, 1));
}

console.log(dates);
```

Comment: You are wellcome :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you want different solution, but I think following can be a solution of your problem with nested loops.

```js
var today = new Date();
var result = [];
for (var i = 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
    var yr = today.getFullYear() - i;
    var mnth = ("0" + j).slice(-2);
    result.push({
      month: mnth,
      year: yr,
      myDate: yr + "-" + mnth
    })
  }
}
console.log(result);
```